# Not able to run the app due to import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, compiler-errors, react-native-screens

I am trying to run the app for the Android platform but it's always failing. Can anyone please help me please check below the screenshot of the error while compiling the build for Android?

[image: error]

> error: cannot find symbol import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;

Steps to reproduce:

```
npm i react-native-screens
npm run android
```

build is compiling and throwing errors as per the below:

```
error: 
android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:33: 
error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
```

Comment: I still have this problem. None of these solutions have worked. Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 3):

You probably has installed some dependencies using a package manager and some with other.

Check if you have `package-lock.json` **and** `yarn.lock` or another similar file from other package manager. Keep just the one from what you're using (yarn, npm, pnpm...) and remove all others.

Then run the command to install everything from `package.json` (ex. `npm install` or just `yarn`). This will make sure all dependencies listed at `package.json` has been installed with the same package manager.

> Remember, if you kept `yarn.lock` so run `yarn` if you kept `package-lock.json` then run `npm install`.

After it just start your application as usual, and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 3):

This React Native Screen version is not compatible with React Native 0.72 or higher.

To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

Open your project's build.gradle file at the project level.
Add the following line inside the buildscript block, which defines the Kotlin version:

```
classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
```

Make sure your buildscript block looks something like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // ... other configurations ...
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        // ... other dependencies ...
    }
}
```

By adding this line, you specify the Kotlin version for your project.

Sync your Gradle project to apply these changes.
This should resolve the compatibility issue with React Native 0.72+ for your React Native Screen version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Unfortunately, I am not a Java or an Android developer, so I didn't know how to track down the reason that the Java packages were missing or why the were not being imported correctly.

I removed the four packages that appeared to be the source of the error, via `npm remove`:

- `@react-navigation/native`
- `@react-navigation/native-stack`
- `react-native-safe-area-context`
- `react-native-screens`

And then added them using `yarn add` instead of `npm install`. After running `yarn install`, the project loaded without those errors.

I'm running a new project, and I meant to use `yarn` instead of `npm` anyway, so this suffices for me. Sorry I can't be of more valuable help. :\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Android simulator after installing React Navigation. Here is what worked for me:

I removed the following packages using `npm remove`:

- @react-navigation/native
- @react-navigation/native-stack
- react-native-safe-area-context
- react-native-screens

I then reinstalled them with npm adding the `--save` flag. Once I reinstalled them, my Android simulator started without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I downgraded OpenJDK to v11 and created a new project. Then the problem was solved.